# Use TLS 1.2 in TFS Webhooks

Tags: ssl, tfs, tls1.2

I'm trying to setup a Webhook in `TFS` to target an internal `HTTPS` server.
I'm getting this error when I attempt to test the url:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request. 
>   ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted:
>   Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. 
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, TransportContext& context) 
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar) 
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Common.HttpActionTask.

The `Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel` error happens because `TFS` uses `TLS 1.0` to open the connection to the remote server, and that server only accepts `TLS 1.2` requests.

How can we configure the Webhook to use `TLS 1.2`?

Answer (score 1):

try this before make the request:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @federico. That's indeed the fix to use in C# or Powershell. But I'm not in charge of any code in that case; I'm using a TFS WebHook (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/get-started), so I've got no option (that I can see) to change the ServicePointManager settings.

Comment: I'm struggeling with the same issue, trying to call an internal Openshift 4.5 with auto signed certificate... did you solve it @ndeslandes?